# What Happens If I Combine DW And String In 8086 Assembly

Tags: assembly

I'm Not Exactly Sure What Happens If I Combine DW And String In 8086 Assembly. If You Don't Know What I'm Talking About, You Can See An Example Of What I Mean Below.

var: DW "Hello World!"

Please Let Me Know. Thanks!

Comment: If you assemble that and look at the resulting machine code, what do you see?

Comment: Depends on the assembler.  [How are dw and dd different from db directives for strings?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38860174) / [Difference between db and dw when defining strings](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28076943) cover NASM.  [When using the MOV mnemonic to load/copy a string to a memory register in MASM, are the characters stored in reverse order?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57427904) covers MASM.